# Help evaluating the following derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Since $$3y=\cos(x),$$ $$\frac{dy}{dt}=5,$$find $\displaystyle \frac{dx}{dt}$ when $\displaystyle x=\frac{\pi}{2}.$

My approach involved letting $y=f(t)$ and letting $x=g(t)$, which implies that, since $$y=\frac{\cos(x)}{3},$$then$$f(t)=\frac{\cos(g(t))}{3}$$and hence, by the quotient rule, $$f'(t)=-\frac{\sin(g(t))\cdot g'(t)}{3}=5$$ which further implies that $$g'(t)=-\frac{15}{\sin(g(t))}$$ although at this point I'm pretty firmly stuck. For the record, I've not yet started or even looked into multivariable calculus, this is all happening, in my head, in the 2D plane. Either way, any help is appreciated.

Comment: What kind of attitude is "mind you"?

Comment: Just a heads up? Or does it imply something else? @KennyLau

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have defined $x=g(t)$ and you know that $ x= \pi/2 $ you get $ sin(g(t))=sin(\pi/2)$=1. Therefore the  result is$$ g'(t)=-\frac{15}{\sin(g(t))}=-15$$

Answer (score 1):

$3\dfrac{dy}{dt}=\dfrac{d}{dt}\cos x=-\sin x\dfrac{dx}{dt}$, now put $x=\pi/2$ and $\dfrac{dy}{dt}=5$ to calculate $\dfrac{dx}{dt}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$y=\frac{\cos x}{3} \implies \frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}=\frac{-\sin x}{3}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}=5$$

$$x=\frac{\pi}{2}\implies \frac{-1}{3}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}=5 \implies \frac{\partial x}{\partial t}=-15$$